# Excel Conditional Formatting formula fill rule resets to same colour (IN CDM)

Tags: excel, cognos

I'm having trouble with a conditional formatting rule, although it is in conjunction between IBM Cognos Disclosure Management 10.2.4.7 and Excel 2010 so may not be that easy to understand.

Essentially I have 3 conditional formatting rules applied to Cell A1 which will colour the cell red amber or green depending on if the value in Cell B1 is "R", "A", "G". The rule looks like =$B$1="R" then fill = Red etc

This rule works fine in a normal instance of Excel 2010, but in conjunction with CDM every time I save the excel object it reverts the fill of all the rules to the colour of the last rule entered - so in the example above all three would be green.

I've tried exporting the Excel files from CDM and applying the rules / saving the file which works ok, but when I reimport the file to CDM it once again reverts all the fill to a single colour.

I think its reasonably clear from this that there is a bug in CDM causing this, but I need to try and understand what could be causing it so that I could find a work around... anybody got any ideas?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hi No I haven't, but it isn't the output in the Cell that is the problem. My undersatnding of this feature is that it will prevent the calculation moving to the next rule set if it finds a rule that applies in the 1st or second positon. The problem here is that the rule itself shows the wrong fill colour so even if they all execute the outcome would be the same colour regardless of the answer. Image showing issue added to question.

Comment: Is it possible to do that based on an external cell value? - I can see how you'd do it on the current cell value, but the cells we are formatting have "JAN" in them rather than a number or RAG.